# pandas .replace removes first value but doesn't add second

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I am attempting to replace data in a .csv column: '1(1789-1790)' with a single year: '1789'

I first read the .csv:

```
df = pd.read_csv('congress1.csv', delimiter = ';', names = ['Name', 'Years', 'Position', 'Party', 'State', 'Congress'], header = 0)
```

Then I run .replace on data in column='Congress' and provide it with the new string:

```
df['Congress'] = df['Congress'].replace('1(1789-1790)', '1789', inplace=True)
```

However, when I print my data that column shows "None."

Answer (score 1):

When you use `inplace=True` the `replace` method returns `None` (which you then reassign to) and modifies the object in-place.

Demo:

```
>>> s = pd.Series([1,2,3])
>>> s
>>> 
0    1
1    2
2    3
dtype: int64
>>> 
>>> res = s.replace(1, 2, inplace=True)
>>> res is None
>>> True
>>> s
>>> 
0    2
1    2
2    3
dtype: int64
```

`s` has been modified in-place, `res` is `None`!

You can simply omit the `inplace=True` part or don't reassign to `df['Congress']`.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that's what inplace does. However, now the data remains unchanged. I'll update the original question to reflect.

Comment: @CharlieGoldberg well, it's pretty much a new question now. I have answered why you were getting a column filled wih `None`, but I cannot answer your new question without seeing the dataframe. I suggest that instead of editing this question you open a new one. Make sure to include a [MCVE] such that others can fully reproduce the problem.